# [MySQL]Populate a column depending on the value of different column which is a foreign key.

Tags: mysql, oracle10g, database-schema

I have two tables TableA and TableB.

```
 TableA(acolumn1,acolumn2,abcolumn(primarykey)) 

 TableB(abcolumn,bcolumn1,acolumn1).
```

TableA is a static table where there will be no insertions or deletions.

When inserting values in TableB

insert into TableB (abcolumn,bcolumn1) values("val1","val2");

The third column in TableB(acolumn1) should be filled automatically from the TableA depending on TableB(abcolumn).

Wanted to know If i can create TableB with a similar query below.

create table TableB(abcoulmn datatype,bcolumn1 datatype,acolumn1 datatype Set TableA.acolumn1 where abcolumn=TableA.abcolumn)

The above query is wrong and it is just to make people understand what i require.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As it is tagged [tag:oracle10g] as well: No - not exactly such an option in Oracle 10g.

What should be the effect of it, anyway?  
You mention the original insert but do not talk about later updates to TableB - whether or not the values in TableB.abcolumn and TableB.acolumn1 need to stay in synch (in which case the latter column doesn't seem to make much sense - except, maybe, for being used in a natural join).
If, however, acolumn1 will never be updated - providing kind of a historic record, enforcing some business rule -- you could use an `INSERT` trigger to this effect.

Comment: If you still need a hand with this, please, provide more detail. Might be easier to assist you, if you clarify, what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @Abecee. Thank you so much for the reply. In response to your reply I've thought about the schema  design and changed it accordingly which will serve my purpose.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Good luck.